# Firebase cloud function node depreciation warning

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Recently when I deploy cloud functions the logs on firebase are showing this warning/error

> (node:2) DeprecationWarning: grpc.load: Use the @grpc/proto-loader
>   module with grpc.loadPackageDefinition instead

Has anyone encountered this and know what the problem is / how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-vision/issues/120